# webpack error on build run. 'Error: Cannot find module '@webassemblyjs/ast''

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I' am currently working in React, and I'm trying to setup webpack and webpack-cli. I am currently following the tutorial on webpack 4 tutorial site https://www.valentinog.com/blog/webpack-4-tutorial/ using my command line I've been trying to install webpack and webpack-cli as my dependencies using nodejs.

I've been entering `npm i webpack --save-dev` and `npm i webpack-cli --save-dev`
 Both these modules install correctly and are added to my package.json as dependencies.

```
 {
  "name": "webpack-4-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.10.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.4"
  }
}
```

I also have a scripts section that has a "build": "webpack" which should initialize my webpack. But when I type `npm run build` i get this error. `Error: Cannot find module '@webassemblyjs/ast'`. I've checked my node_modules and @webassemblyjs is there.

I've tried uninstalling my node_modules, reinstalling webpack and webpack-cli and even moved to a different directory and repository to see if I could change my outcome that way. However, I'm still getting this cannot find module @webassemblyjs/ast. I'm currently running MacOs High Sierra, and am not sure if maybe it's just not agreeing with my operating system. If anything I haven't noticed any other Stackoverflow posts dealing with this specific error, so I thought I'd make a post asking for help.

Thankyou for your time!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. After trying many variations of version, deleting node modules a couple times, trying to manually install the library, I finally solved it by running

```
npm ci
```

~1 day hours of debugging, 6 letter command. Computers are so fun sometimes

Answer (score 0):

try this

update "webpack": "^4.10.1" to "webpack": "^3.11.0"

Comment: Thankyou! I've just installed webpack version 3.11.0. I think I'll need to create a config file when using this version. But so far I don't have that error using 3 instead of 4.

Answer (score 0):

No issues on macOS High Sierra with:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.12.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8"
}
```

Try first upgrading to those versions and see if that resolves the issue.

Also, are you using a private registry? If so, you might be getting something like this if `@webassemblyjs` can't be found in it:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @webassemblyjs/ast@1.5.12
```

You could quickly fix this by adding `@webassemblyjs:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org` in your `.npmrc` file.

Otherwise, you could try running [`webpack --display-error-detail`](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#debug-options) and see if you get additional details about the error.